# Trouble understanding the constant portion of Big O

Tags: computer-science, big-o

Can someone explain to me the purpose of the constant portion of big O notation?

I'll try and explain where I am at right now in terms of understanding:

Basically you have a function, for example `f(x) = x^2 + 1` and `g(x) = x^3`

So, `f(x)` is `O( g(x) )`, because for a certain value of `x`, `k`, for every `x > k` , `f(x) <= **C**|g(x)|`.

So for this equation, `k = 2`.

I could be wrong already so please correct me if so.

That seems intuitive enough, but I get a little bit confused about the constant value, **C**.

Comment: This is should be on [http://math.stackexchange.com/](http://math.stackexchange.com/).  As [Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people who write code because they love it. We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of **source code** in them](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions)

Comment: O notation is about the shape of a function, not its absolute magnitude. Adding or multiply by a constant doesn't change the shape.

Comment: So wait, if you change the constant, for example if you increase it, then you can just increase the k value too and therefore the function will still be O( the other function) ?? is that how it works?

Comment: The specific values of C and k are not important: the fact that they exist is. Either it is the case that there is some value of k and some value of C such that for every x > k (etc) or there are no such values.

Answer (score 2):

The following line is poorly phrased:

> f(x) is O( g(x) ), because for a certain value of x, k, for every x >
>   k , f(x) <= C|g(x)|

The following is more accurate:

> f(x) is O( g(x) ), because there exists a value k and a value C such
>   that for any value of x greater than k: f(x) <= C|g(x)|.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's just some constant.  To prove f(x) is O(g(x)) you must pick some specific constants C and k and prove they satisfy that condition.  What's so confusing?

Comment: So wait, if you change the constant, for example if you increase it, then you can just increase the k value too and therefore the function will still be O( the other function) ??

Comment: Increasing k wouldn't change anything, because you are interested in what happens to values of x between k and infinity. But you aren't picking a k, you are showing that such a k exists at all. There are no POSSIBLE values of c and k that show that g(x) is O(f(x)).